# How can I get exposed filter for content type from the view programmatically?

Tags: views, 8

I want to customize an exposed filter for content types, how can I get the exposed filter for a view in the code? And to know exactly which content types need to be dispalyed?

```
$route = explode('.', \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName());
if (!empty($route) && $route[0] == 'view') {

  if ($view = Views::getView($route[1])) {
       $filters = $view->getHandlers('filter');

  }
}
```

Comment: It's in `$view->exposed_data`. Not really sure what you mean about which content types to display. Adding your current code and indicating where it's going wrong would probably be a good idea

Comment: I have an exposed filter for content types, where only two content types are available as an option (out of 10 existing in my drupal site). So in my code I need to get which options are available for this filter.

Comment: Can’t this be dictated in the View config?

Comment: it is. But I need this information in my php file.

Comment: I don't have a code sample to hand, buy you probably need to use something like `$field_handlers = $view->getHandlers('filter');` and loop through those to see what you can find

Comment: Unfortunately it does not return the content types

Comment: I did this a while back, when I’m back at a computer I’ll see if I can dig out the code

Comment: Thanks a lot! Related issue to this question is that getView($route[1]) returns the master page for a view and I did not set up any filters there. So basically I need the filters which come from the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to get the display settings from the View storage (the configuration of the view):

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('myview');
$storage = $view->storage;
$display = &$storage->getDisplay('page_1');
$display['display_options']['filters']['nid']['value']['value'] = 123;
$storage->save();
```

Here you should be able to find all options configured in the Views UI.